# gRPC: how many proto services need to have?

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc

What is the best practice in my case?
I have a ASP.NET Web service (REST, SOAP, GraphQL), I am adding gRPC.net to it. The question is:
I need to port ~100 queries.
May I have multiple small proto with separate definitions or should I have some large protos?

Answer (score 1):

Some best practice article like https://medium.com/@akhaku/protobuf-definition-best-practices-87f281576f31 could be helpful